# C# Forms - Setting the text enter cursor

Tags: c#, regex, forms, textbox

I'm currently making a basic calculator form and to this point I've used a Regex method to restrict any character that's not an operator(+,-,*,etc.) or a number.

I've also implemented it so if they enter an illegal character an error msg pops up as well as deleting the last char in the text box entered.

```
Regex LegalChars = new Regex(@"[^0-9 + - * / % .]");

MatchCollection Matches = LegalChars.Matches(UserInput.Text);

if (Matches.Count > 0) {
    MessageBox.Show("You can only enter what is shown on the calculator\nI.e. No letters or different symbols");            
    UserInput.Text = DeleteLastChar(UserInput.Text); //couldn't get .TrimEnd to work so i made my own function         
}
```

But I noticed if you paste something like "5*a+6-12" it will delete every single character until it deletes the a(i.e. its now "5*"), also if you enter an illegal character in the middle of the textbox chars it does the same thing.

Any solutions to this problem? i.e. A way to delete all illegal characters but only the illegal characters. Or better yet the exact way the Windows calculator is implemented - you can't enter illegal chars at all

Comment: can you show your `DeleteLastChar` function?

Comment: Assuming you are building a Winforms application, there is a better solution for this problem, and it's called a MaskedTextBox. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: `Regex LegalChars = new Regex(@"[^0-9 + - * / % .]");` should read **IllegalChars** and not contain spaces. `Regex IllegalChars = new Regex(@"[^0-9+-*/%.]");`

Comment: @KM 
 private string DeleteLastChar(string Input)
        {
            string Output = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < Input.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                Output += Input[i];
            }
            return Output;
        } //Came up with this on the whim

Comment: @ZP Didn't know that was a thing; I'll probably implement it with a MaskedTextBox

Answer (score 0):

The regex to check for illegal characters in a basic calculator is `@"[^0-9+/*()-]"`. It will match any character other than a digit, `+`, `/`, `*`, `(`, `)`, `-`. You may add more, as in your example: `%`, and `.`.

Then, you can either check the OnTextChanged event, or OnKeyPress. I myself prefer OnKeyPress as it allows intercepting keyboard input before the text changes at all.

Here is sample code assuming your `TextBox` object is called `textBox1`:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
...
textBox1.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(textBox1_KeyPress);
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (Regex.IsMatch(e.KeyChar.ToString(), @"[^0-9+/*()%.-]"))
    {
        e.Handled = true; // Do not allow input
    }
}
```

Comment: Just became enlightened to the "MaskedTextBox", are there any pros or cons of this method or the MTB?

Comment: I would not use MaskedTextBox (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for a calculator. It is great if you have special format, and only want to get back numeric values, but in a calculator, you will just work with numbers not caring of the format, I guess.